# How can I get the number of accounts that viewed a question?

Tags: discussion, views

We can see a question's views by looking at the top of the question. But some people might view the question multiple times. How can I get the number of *unique* viewers? Perhaps using a SEDE query?

Comment: @W.O. no, it's not. After 15 minutes, it'll count as a new view. It's impossible to know the number of unique views, as that isn't stored.

Comment: @Glorfindel well, there are the traffic logs, but extracting from them unique visitors of specific question isn't really a simple task.